# Drawing with EGL in Qt

Tags: qt, egl

I'm trying to get Qt and EGL to work together. I'm working on a program that uses EGL to draw, and I have to use Qt to create a GUI overlay.

The current solution was to turn a QWidget into a native window, and pass it's window handle to EGL. This works, but it's difficult to work with. Qt isn't aware that the widget is being drawn in by something else. So when another widget is overlaid, even if it's transparent, the image drawn by EGL is erased. The only way to get them to work is if I jigsaw the buttons and other GUI elements in a way that they don't overlap the parts of the native window I want to show. However this means that I can't use layouts or QML or any of the tools that would make creating different GUIs easy.

So my question is, how can I draw with EGL into Qt in a more usable way.

I'm working with Qt 5.4.2 by the way. If absolutely necessary, I might be able to upgrade to 5.5, but newer versions won't work.

I was looking into QOpenGLContext, and ways to make it use the context created by EGL, but I can't seem to find any good examples on how to actually go about doing this.

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?